# Adding Patient Information Failure in form and database

Tags: php, mysqli, compiler-errors, crud, addition

I am a student and I a am making a system for our project. I want to Add information but when I input data in my form, no data has been added. I tried checking my database and there's no data added. Please help.

I tried checking my database and everything are all good. EVerything are matched in my codes but I still cant add information in my database

```
Here are my codes:





`<?php


session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserLogin'])){
 
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit;
}

include_once('connections.php');
$con = connection();

if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['date_of_birth']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['state']) && isset($_POST['medical_history']) && isset($_POST['date_of_admission']) && isset($_POST['diagnoses']) && isset($_POST['prescription']) && isset($_POST['phone_number'])) {

    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
    $date_of_birth = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date_of_birth']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);
    $medical_history = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['medical_history']);
    $date_of_admission = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date_of_admission']);
    $diagnoses = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['diagnoses']);
    $prescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['prescription']);
    $phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone_number']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO patient_rec (First_name, Last_name, Date_of_birth, Gender, Address, Category, State, Medical_history, Date_of_admission, Diagnoses, Prescription, Phone_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $first_name, $last_name, $date_of_birth, $gender, $address, $category, $state, $medical_history, $date_of_admission, $diagnoses, $prescription, $phone_number);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    

    mysqli_close($con);
    session_write_close();

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    
    ?>


<?php

session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['UserLogin']) || !$_SESSION['UserLogin']) {

  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=.75">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addform.css">
  <body>
</br>
<h1>Add Patient Information</h1>
<h2>Bayawan District hospital</h2>
<h3>236 Zamora St, Bayawan City, 6221 Negros Oriental</h3>
</br>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
  <form action="add.php" method="POST">
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Please type your first name" required><br>
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Please type your last name" required><br>
  <label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:</label><br>
  <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" required><br>
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender_male"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_female"> Female<br>
  <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Please type your address" required><br>
  <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" pattern="[0-9]{11}" required>

  <label for="category">Category:</label><br>
  <select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option value="">-Select Choices-</option>
    <option value="Primary Care">Primary Care</option>
    <option value="Specialty Care">Specialty Care</option>
    <option value="Emergency Care">Emergency Care</option>
    <option value="Urgent Care">Urgent Care</option>
    <option value="Long-term Care">Long-term Care</option>
    <option value="Hospice Care">Hospice Care</option>
    <option value="Mental Healthcare">Mental Healthcare</option>

  </select><br>
  <label for="state">Status:</label><br>
  <select name="state" id="state" required><br>
  <option value="">-Select Choices-</option>
  <option value="New patient">New patient</option>
  <option value="Established patient">Established patient</option>
  <option value="Outpatient">Outpatient</option>
  <option value="Inpatient">Inpatient</option>
</select><br>

  <label for="medical_history">Medical History:</label><br>
  <textarea name="medical_history" id="medical_history" placeholder="Please type here..." rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br>
<label for="date_of_admission">Date of Admission:</label><br>
<input type="date" name="date_of_admission" id="date_of_admission" required><br>
<label for="diagnoses">Diagnoses:</label><br>
<textarea name="diagnoses" id="diagnoses" placeholder="Please type here..." rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br>
<label for="prescription">Prescription:</label><br>
<textarea name="prescription" id="prescription" placeholder="Please type here..." rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Patient">
<a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="logbtn">Cancel</button></a>
</form>
</body>
`
```

Comment: Does the number of bind parameters match the number of `s`'s you have in your call to `bind_param()`.

Comment: what you should be checking for is **PHP errors**. Errors is a way for a program to tell a programmer what's wrong with it.

Comment: on a side note, you shouldn't use mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Nigel Ren. Thank youuu! I was worried. Its all good now. My number S is lacking